# how can i obtain the response off server and if this contains "open" i can call other method, "contains" always marks error

Tags: java, android

/*Method that sends the GPS pulse every time, when receiving the answer of the server if it contains "open" I have to stop sending pulse The method of eliminating the pulse I already have, I just have to know if the server response contains "open" because the response from the Server is too large string coming from a JSON*/

```
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;

        final String routeId = ControlClass.pref.getString("routeId", "inaccesible");
        int routeId2= Integer.parseInt(routeId);
        try {
            URL url = new URL(params[0]);
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            urlConnection.setUseCaches(false);
            urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
            urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                    "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

            DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(urlConnection.getOutputStream());
            JSONObject jsonParam = new JSONObject();
            jsonParam.put("route_id", routeId2);
            jsonParam.put("timestamp", timestamp);
            jsonParam.put("lat", 19.5216103);
            jsonParam.put("lon", -99.21071050509521);

            Log.d("BANDERA", "LIVE TRACKING");
            Log.d("JSON DEL LIVE TRACKING", jsonParam.toString());
            System.out.println("Latitud y longitud" + currentLatitude + currentLongitude);


            wr.writeBytes(jsonParam.toString());
            wr.flush();
            wr.close();
            urlConnection.connect();
               try {
                    InputStream is = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                    bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
                    String line;
                    StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
                    while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                        response.append(line);
                        response.append('\r');
                    }
                    bufferedReader.close();
                    if(serverAnswer.contains("open"))
                        killGps();
                    serverAnswer = response.toString();
                    System.out.println("LIVE TRACKING RESPONSE" +  serverAnswer);
                    Log.d("LIVE TRACKING RESPONSE", serverAnswer);
                    return response.toString();
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                     Log.d("ERROR: ", "File not found en servidor Response: " + serverAnswer);
                }

            } catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            } finally{
                if (urlConnection != null) {
                    urlConnection.disconnect();
                }
                try {
                    if (bufferedReader != null) {
                        bufferedReader.close();
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return serverAnswer;
    }

}
```

Comment: Did you have a question? Does your code work? What's the problem?

Comment: if(serverAnswer.contains("open"))
                        killGps();    , 
In this part I always return a null, although in the answer if it contains "open"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need the entire response, don't store it. Just search each line as you stream it, and exit once you find the text you're looking for:

```
while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
    if (line.contains("open")) {
        killGps();
        break;
    }
}
```